# How to retrieve values set in Hashable paths when using a router to navigate through views

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am using an enum as Hashable and a Router as ObservableObject to navigate through views.
I send an id as parameter for the Form path and I would like to retrieve this is id in the Form view

```
enum Paths: Hashable{

    // An id is sent as parameter to be retrieved in the view
    case Form(id: String)
}

final class Router<T: Hashable>: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var paths: [T] = []
    
    func push(_ path: T){
        paths.append(path)
    }
    
}
```

When I go from any view to the Form view, I would like to retrieve the value of the id sent in the Form path

In a view I may have a button that make the user go to the Form view

```
Button {
   router.push(.Form(id:"foo"))
}
```

Then, in the Form view I want to retrieve the id set when clicking on the button

```
struct FormView: View{

    @EnvironmentObject var router: Router<Paths>


    var body: some View{
        
        
      VStack{
            Text("\(id)") <--- How can I retrieve the id sent in the Form path?
      }
   }
}
```

How can I do so? I know I could set additional @Published fields in the router and retrieve these fields in the view but I think that would bloat the router and it seems more elegant to me to set the views parameters in the paths that lead to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid downcasting whenever get the id from `paths` array, you can wrap it within a protocol to provide a unique id. Try these:

```swift
protocol Pathable: Hashable {
    var id: String { get }
}

enum Paths: Pathable {
    // An id is sent as parameter to be retrieved in the view
    case Form(id: String)
    
    var id: String {
        switch self {
        case .Form(let id):
            return id
        }
    }
}

final class Router<T: Pathable>: ObservableObject {
    ...
}
```

Then get it in `FormView` (I assume the path you want always is the last element of array)

```swift
struct FormView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var router: Router<Paths>
    
    var id: String {
        router.paths.last?.id ?? ""
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("id here \(id)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. However, my guess is that the Paths will end up bloated if I have like 10 paths and each of them require an id to be passed into the view.

Comment: How about making `paths` like a stack? I mean remove the last element when you push back from navigation controller. It will guarantee the array just holds a few paths at the same time. It's just a way to handle path array.